# Select multi item in animated list view and remove them?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

How can I select multi item in `Animated List` and remove them on the list?

The select function is simple but how can I delete the selected item or remove it from the `Animated list`?

```
AnimatedList(
          key: _key,
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8),
          shrinkWrap: true,
          initialItemCount: _data!.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index, animation) {
            return InkWell(
              onTap: () {
                _data![index].isSelect = !_data![index].isSelect!;
                if (_data![index].isSelect == true) {
                  selectedItem!.add(_data![index]);
                } else if (_data![index].isSelect == false) {
                  selectedItem!.remove(_data![index]);
                }
                print(
                  selectedItem!.asMap(),
                );

                if (indexS.contains(_data![index])) {
                  indexS.remove(_data![index]);
                } else {
                  indexS.add(_data![index]);
                }

                print("**********************");
                print(indexS.length.toString());
                print("**********************");
                setState(() {});
              },
              child: SizeTransition(
                sizeFactor: animation,
                child: Container(
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                    vertical: 5,
                    horizontal: 15,
                  ),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                    horizontal: 3,
                    vertical: 6,
                  ),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      // backgroundBlendMode: BlendMode.lighten,
                      color: (_data![index].isSelect == true)
                          ? const Color(0xffe2e6ee)
                          : Colors.transparent,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12)),
                  child: MyItem(
                    _data![index].title!,
                    // onDelete: () => removeItem(index),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            );
          }),
```

Answer (score -1):

To add or remove from an AnimatedList you should use

```
_key.currentState.insertItem() // to add
_key.currentState.removeItem() // to remove
```

In your case would be something like that:

```
onTap: () {
    _data![index].isSelect = !_data![index].isSelect!;
    if (_data![index].isSelect == true) {
        selectedItem!.add(_data![index]);
        _key.currentState.insertItem(_data![index]); // add this line
    } else if (_data![index].isSelect == false) {
        selectedItem!.remove(_data![index]);
        _key.currentState.removeItem(_data![index], builder); // add this line
    }
    print(
        selectedItem!.asMap(),
    );

    if (indexS.contains(_data![index])) {
        indexS.remove(_data![index]);
    } else {
        indexS.add(_data![index]);
    }

    print("**********************");
    print(indexS.length.toString());
    print("**********************");
    setState(() {}); 
},
```

You should also provide some `AnimatedListRemovedItemBuilder`, eg:

```
AnimatedListRemovedItemBuilder builder = (context, animation) {
   return SizeTransition(
     sizeFactor: animation,
     child: Card(
       child: Text("Item"),
     ),
   );
};
```

Comment: yup, I know that. I mean how can I once remove multi-item?